# Do tag points get updated if a tag is added to a question after an answer was already provided?

Tags: discussion

Please consider the following scenario:

1. A question is asked by User1
2. User2 answers the question
3. The answer (by User2) was upvoted or accepted
4. User2 gets tag points according to the original question tags
5. User2 (or other user) edits the tags (retags the question)

**Question**:
Will the tag count be updated after step 5 according to the retag?

Comment: Yes, they will.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thanks

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier How do you know it?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson It's been confirmed here on meta several times. It is not the first time this question pops up.